# How to assign each element in an array column its ordered position?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tuples

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4],
                  'x':[np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan,2,np.nan,3,3,4,2,1,1,3],
                  'y':[np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan,1,np.nan,1,1,5,1,5,1,1]})


group   x   y
  1    nan  nan
  1    nan  nan 
  1    3.0  2.0
  1    nan  nan 
  1    2.0  1.0
  2    nan  nan 
  2    3.0  1.0
  2    3.0  1.0
  2    4.0  5.0
  3    2.0  1.0
  3    1.0  5.0
  4    1.0  1.0
  4    3.0  1.0
```

Basically, lets say I have 4 groups and each group contains points with x,y coordinates. Points can have the same coordinates. For example (3,1) exists (twice) in group 2 and also in group 4. Furthermore if x is nan then y should also be `nan`

I want to assign each pair (x,y) its corresponding position with respect to the sorted list of tuples. If `x=y=nan` then zero should be returned.
Hence the output should be:

```
group    x    y   label_global
  1     nan  nan       0
  1     nan  nan       0
  1     3.0  2.0       5
  1     nan  nan       0
  1     2.0  1.0       3
  2     nan  nan       0
  2     3.0  1.0       4
  2     3.0  1.0       4
  2     4.0  5.0       6
  3     2.0  1.0       3
  3     1.0  5.0       2
  4     1.0  1.0       1
  4     3.0  1.0       4
```

What I have done is the following:

```
centroids = sorted(set([x for x in zip(df.dropna().x.values, df.dropna().y.values)]))
df['label_global'] = [centroids.index(d) + 1 if d[1]==d[1] else 0 for d in zip(df.x.values, df.y.values)]
```

Is there a better way to do this please? My dataframe is about 2million lines long and it takes around 3mins for the task to complete

As a sidenote: In the last list comprehension, the expression  `if d[1]==d[1] else` is meant to filter out tuples with `nan` since `np.nan==np.nan` evaluates to `False`. I had initially tried with `if np.nan not in d else`, ie:

```
df['label_global'] = [centroids.index(d) + 1 if np.nan not in d else 0 for d in zip(df.x.values, df.y.values)]
```

but that doesnt work and I have no idea why. It returns a value error:

`ValueError: (nan, nan) is not in list`

which to me indicates that the `if else` loop hasn't worked. Any insights are very much welcome.

I find it also a bit strange that

`(np.nan, np.nan)==(np.nan, np.nan)` returns `True`

or even

`(np.nan,)==(np.nan,)` returns `True`

but

`np.nan==np.nan` returns `False`

Comment: Why is `4,5` in group 2 `6`?

Comment: @Erfan: Because pair `(3,2)` from group 1 has been given `label 5`. Pair `(4, 5)` comes next and has been assigned with `label 6`

Comment: This won't help you because you're sorting over multiple columns and want to group same values into same groups, but a related function is `df.x.argsort()`, which gives you the indices that would put that column in order (assigning `-1` to `nan` values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort by x,y pairs, setting nan first, and use cumsum to set group numbers

```
df['label_global'] = df.sort_values(['x','y'], na_position='first') \ 
                     [['x','y']].fillna(0).diff().ne([0,0]).any(1).cumsum()-1

   group    x    y  label_global
0       1  NaN  NaN             0
1       1  NaN  NaN             0
2       1  3.0  2.0             5
3       1  NaN  NaN             0
4       1  2.0  1.0             3
5       2  NaN  NaN             0
6       2  3.0  1.0             4
7       2  3.0  1.0             4
8       2  4.0  5.0             6
9       3  2.0  1.0             3
10      3  1.0  5.0             2
11      4  1.0  1.0             1
12      4  3.0  1.0             4
```

Comment: Brilliant! A lot better than mine,many thanks. Didnt event know about the `.ne()` method